# Replace double quotes in text enclosed with double quotes in CSV file with back slash using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell.
I need to replace double quotes inside a text as below with `\"` in CSV file.

Input:
"Te"st1","Tes"t2","Test"3"

Output:
"Te`\`"st1","Tes`\`"t2","Test`\`"3"

I tried with **-replace**. But it is replacing all double quotes in CSV file. Need to replace quotes only inside the text.

`$csv = 'C:\Users\Suresh\Documents\test.txt' (Get-Content $csv) -replace '"','\"' | out-file 'C:\Users\Suresh\Documents\test_out.txt'`

Comment: So you want to replace every third, starting from the second instance of `"`? Or can one value/column contain multiple unescaped `"`'s?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, One column can contain multiple unescaped `".

Comment: I don't think your input can be unambiguously parsed.

Comment: Not good at `regex` but try with something like this, might work for you: `'"Te"st1","Tes"t2","Test"3","Test4"",""Test5"' -replace '([\w"])"([\w"])','$1\"$2'`

Comment: In a csv, when a field contains a quote, that quote should be **doubled**, not prefixed with a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 -replace '(?<=\w)\"(?=\w)','\"'
```

Example

```
$tempfile = New-TemporaryFile

@'
"Column1","Column2","Column3"
"Te"st1","Tes"t2","Test"3"
'@ | Set-Content $tempfile

(Get-Content $tempfile) -replace '(?<=\w)\"(?=\w)','\"' | Set-Content $tempfile

Get-Content $tempfile
```

output

```
"Column1","Column2","Column3"
"Te\"st1","Tes\"t2","Test\"3"
```

The regex pattern uses a look ahead and look behind to only act upon double quotes that have a word character on both sides of it. You could adjust to accept more than just word characters adjacent. You could also go the opposite direction, for example only work on those that don't have a comma before/after.

Comment: Nice one, how would you go about if you have these two? `"Test4"",""Test5"`. Should it be like this? `'(?<=[\w"])\"(?=[\w"])','\"'`

Comment: That wouldn't be a valid CSV file.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just curious how should the `regex` look, I love learning this and getting better at this.

Comment: For this complex requirement, this could work.

-replace '(?<=[^\",])\"(?=\")|(?<=\")\"(?=[^\",])','\"'

Says work on double quote that is preceded by (not " or ,) and is followed by (") OR work on double quote that is preceded by (") and is followed by (not " or ,)

Comment: Yep, I was looking at it on regex101. Thank you!

Comment: Regex is incredibly flexible and powerful. You already know though, as you are trying to learn more.

Comment: Nice, but I think you should mention that in a csv, when a field contains a quote, it should be **doubled**, not prefixed with a backslash. You'll see what happens if you do `Import-Csv` on the file with the backslashes as opposed to what happens if you doubled the quotes.